# If $G$ nilpotent and $G/G'$ is cyclic then $G$ is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, nilpotent-groups, derived-subgroup

If $G$ nilpotent and $G/G'$ is cyclic then $G$ is cyclic?

It is very easy to see that this is true when $G$ is finite:
If $G$ is finite nilpotent then all maximal subgroups are normal, so $G/N$ has to be cyclic of other $p$ for some prime $p$.
So all maximal subgroups contain $G'=[G,G]$. And so $G'$ is contained in the frattini subgroup $\text{Frat}(G)$.
It follows that $G=\langle x,\text{Frat}(G) \rangle=\langle x\rangle$.
In the last step we also use that $G$ is finite.

But what happens if $G$ is infinite. Is the statement still true?